# Contact us form - PHP script is not working

Tags: php

I have a situation here. I have a contact us form in HTML connected with PHP script and Google Captcha V2 that is working great on one address . Now,I copied everything and paste it on other server and changed all the keys for the Captcha and that is working great. But when I press submit button, it takes me to contact.php and nothing is happening  .

So HTML form works, CSS WORKS , ReCaptcha v2 WOrks, PHP no !

Comment: only captcha is not working or entire form??

Comment: Please update your question clarifying that the form is the one not working, and not the recaptcha. Where is your form sending the data to? Maybe you are pointing to an address from the place where you copied the html.

Comment: When Submit  button is clicked PHP script starts , right!? Method _POST. Ok, What I just did is , I uploaded fully functional WEBSITE (currently active on other server ) on the server where I have problem, and same thing is happening .

Answer (score 0):

yes when you generate the recaptcha keys it asks for the domain , you need to specify your new site's address also

Comment: Yes I know that. ReCaptcha is working just fine. I know all about secret key and the rest of the stuff about the captcha itself. Like I said , recaptcha is working fine, bu when I press SUBMIT button , it takes me to contact.php address and nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your recaptcha web and access with the account that configured that key. Then simply add the new domain for that key. Just remember it can take up to an hour for the change to impact on your web.

Comment: Thanks. But recaptcha is working just fine. It is more like that php script is not workin in some reason. But that one I used a lot in a past